# How to access HTTP WWW-Authenticate:basic input as varibles in a CGI file

Tags: bash, shell, http

I am writing a CGI using Bash to work between the browser and the server.

The logic should be: if the user is not logged in, then use the following code to trigger the login dialog:

```sh
echo "Status: 401 Unauthorized"
echo "WWW-Authenticate: Basic"
```

The user would have to fill out the system login dialog and submit.

I hope to access the user inputs so I could process the variables and do a HttpRequest to the server.

The server is: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo "Status: 401 Unauthorized"
echo "WWW-Authenticate: Basic"
```

Comment: Can you show some sample input and output?

Comment: @Mihir with a system (or more specifically, I feel it's decided by browsers) popup login window, user should be able to input username/password, let's say 'user;123456' and then click on to submit. I hope to find a way to access these info to like a variable.

Comment: @BinhyuH, check [this](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/BashShellCgi.html) out. May help you.

Comment: @Mihir Thanks, I couldn't work it out by shell as I am new to shell and CGI. I moved on to creating different HTML content like a new login page and it works.